# Receive Broadcast for background data restriction < android 7

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

[This](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/data-saver.html) document and it tells that a broadcast is sent whenever there is a change of the background data restriction. The api docs also say that the `ACTION_BACKGROUND_DATA_SETTING_CHANGED` constant is deprecated and not sent anymore.

But is there any broadcast that an app can receive, when the user restricts the background data of the apps prior to android 7?

Comment: yup, you gotta use Connectivity Manager.It's written in the docs https://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/data-saver.html

Comment: Thank you, but the document only talks about how to do the broadcastReceiver in Android 7, not for Android 6 or 5 :)

Comment: Any workaround for < Android 7.0?

Comment: @YousufSohail Unfortunately, I haven't found any. Sorry